# Node JS go to next FOR cycle

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, break

I just want to bypass item 3, not break the loop.

```
for (var i = 1; i<= 9; i++) {
  if (i==3) break;
  console.log(i);
}
```

Was very unfortunate hunting an answer on Google because I don't really know the magic keywords/technical designation.

**Expected result:**

```
1
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

**Update:** Would like to do the same with a `.forEach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 1; i<= 9; i++) {
  if (i===3) {
    continue;
  }
  console.log(i);
}
```

forEach: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymw4kscb/)

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

numbers.forEach(function(number){
    if(number === 3) {
        return
    }
    console.log(number);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) instead of [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break).

`continue` skips the rest of the loop body and moves on to the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 1; i<= 9; i++) {
  if (i==3) continue;
  console.log(i);
}
```